# Django-registration Admin

Tags: django

I've tried Django-registration, [see this tutorial](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/) to create a full Login-system.

In the tutorials (see STEP 4), I need to update the file urls.py to:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    (r'^$', direct_to_template,
            { 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'),
)
```

But when I do this, the Admin page is not available. When I chance

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root)
```

in

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.urls)
```

The adminpage works; I could login, but I couldn't click on anything... So I couldn't see the registered users.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf).

Answer (score 2):

`admin.site.root` was deprecated in Django 1.1, see [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1/#features-deprecated-in-1-1).

Do you couldn't click on anything because there aren't any links in admin?  If so then you have to login as [superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#creating-superusers).

Also `registration.urls` is deprecated.  The new version of `django-registration` represents a complete rewrite of the previous codebase and improve flexibility so it is a good idea to use version from repository.  It has good [quick-start guide](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/docs/quickstart.rst).